# AWS CloudFront Rout53: An error occurred (IllegalUpdate) when calling the AssociateAlias operation: Invalid or missing alias DNS TXT records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Public HZ "example.net".

There are other records in that HZ

```
one.example.net -> 123one.cloudfront.net
two.example.net -> 456two.cloudfront.net
...
```

I have created a record (bank value ""):

```
example.net -> 789my.cloudfront.net
```

But when I'm trying to associate alias from my CloudFront `789my.cloudfront.net`, I'm getting

```
$ aws cloudfront associate-alias --target-distribution-id "XXX" --alias "example.net"

An error occurred (IllegalUpdate) when calling the AssociateAlias operation: Invalid or missing alias DNS TXT records.
```

TXT record added in HZ:

```
_.example.net -> "789my.cloudfront.net"
```

Any thought?

Comment: Ever find a fix here?

Comment: Do not creating any TXT records at all, just in CloudFront adding 

Alternate domain name (CNAME) "example.net".

Comment: Which sucks little harder to support blue-green deployments

Comment: I ended up having to buy a support plan and opening a ticket. Straight away they were able to tell me there was an API Gateway with the registered apex domain. Once I deleted that, I could and the domain  to the CF distribution and the A record in Route 53. Adding the TXT record did nothing. Why they can't add a proper error telling you where the domain is registered is beyond me when they clearly have the tools. Horrible developer experience.

Comment: Right, sometimes errors messages really misleading